# Select query that will results one value from table1 and one value from table2

Tags: mysql

I am stuck in querying sql database for a scenerio.

```
Table 1:

comp    col1   col2  col3 
nam1     0       0     a
nam2     2       2     b
nam3     5       4     c


table 2:

comp     col1
nam1       2
nam2       2
```

My result should be col1 value 0 in table1 and the same comp value should present in table2 with value in col1..

```
My result be:

comp  col3(table1)   col1(table2)
nam1    a              2
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to join your tables:

```
SELECT comp, table1.col3, table2.col1
FROM   table1 JOIN table2 USING (comp)
WHERE  table1.col1 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try joining both the table like :

```
SELECT t1.col3, COUNT(t2.col1) AS col1
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.comp = t2.comp
WHERE t1.col1 = 0
GROUP BY t2.col1
```